# Auto Increment no

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012-express

I want to auto-increment a serial number:

`"ATN/01-1920" WHERE ATN--given text,01-auto increment,1920--current financial`

The result should be like this:

`'ATN/01-1920','ATN/02-1920','ATN/03-1920'.....`

Also, in a new financial year it should be reset like this: `'ATN/01-2021'`

Answer (score 0):

Give your start date and end date then the script will generate the serial accordingly pass the date in the format YYYYMMDD

```
SELECT  concat('ATN/',format(DATEADD(month, nbr - 1, '19200101'),'MM'),'-', year(DATEADD(month, nbr - 1, '19200101')))
FROM    ( SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY c.object_id ) AS Nbr
          FROM      sys.columns c
        ) nbrs
WHERE   nbr - 1 <= DATEDIFF(MONTH, '19200101', SYSDATETIME())
```

Comment: Does this prevent collisions?

Comment: why start date and end date?is there any requirement? is it not possible to get a financial year from the current date? i want financial wise auto serial no like 'ATN/01-1920','ATN/02-1920','ATN/03-1920'

Comment: so you want from 1920 to current data, try the updated answer?